# How to search data stored in file and display it in list box when search button click?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to search the data, which is stored in a file, when I click on the search button, and show it in list box, in Window phone 7 app..

UI design like this

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboPriority" Height="43" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="246" OpacityMask="#BFBAD5AF" Foreground="Black" Margin="12,61,198,503">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Art" x:Name="minimum" Foreground="Black" Background="White" FontSize="28"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Science" x:Name="maximum" Foreground="Black" Background="White"  FontSize="28" ></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Entertenment" Foreground="Black" Background="White"  FontSize="28"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Politics" Foreground="Black" Background="White"  FontSize="28"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<Button Name="btnSearch" Content="Search" Height="70" Width="150" Margin="293,47,13,483" Click="btnSearch_Click" BorderBrush="#FF100505" Foreground="#FF070101" />
<ListBox Height="359" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,168,0,0" Name="lbList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433" />
```

When I select the category related data from file can display in list box..

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: i want to disply data which is isolated storage in file.

Comment: Then you need to read up on [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage(v=VS.95).aspx) too!